# R & Excel: Creating Pivot Tables & Slicers

Tags: r, excel

Our business users would like us to create exports of the data behind our analyses. The AVP would like to know if we can throw a slicer on the data so the users can filter the data any way they want. Excel slicers are backed by pivot tables, so I'd have to be able to create a pivot table in the Excel workbook first.

I can easily export the data to Excel from R. I can't seem to find an R package that supports the creation of either pivot tables or slicers. Does such a package exist? Or is this simply beyond the scope of any available package at this time?

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but in case somebody ends up here and still needs an answer to the core question:

> I can easily export the data to Excel from R. I can't seem to find an R package that supports the creation of either pivot tables or slicers [in Excel]. Does such a package exist?

Yes, there is thanks to Chris Bailiss. Check out the package [pivottabler](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rpivotTable/index.html), and there's a great vignette walk-through [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pivottabler/vignettes/v12-excelexport.html).

Comment: The link to pivottabler in the answer currently points to the wrong package on CRAN - the correct link is https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pivottabler/index.html  Also, the Excel walkthrough has moved to http://pivottabler.org.uk/articles/v13-excelexport.html due to the package vignettes becoming too large to host on CRAN.

Comment: @cbailiss thanks for those corrections and your time and effort on the package. I've been happily enjoying it for a while now.

Answer (score 0):

There are few package in R which provide these functionality. I suggest you to use  **rpivotTable** and **dplyr**. These are the two packages I often use.

You can study these in detail.

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rpivotTable/rpivotTable.pdf

Comment: rpivotTable renders a pivot table in a browser using JavaScript. My users want to download an Excel Workbook containing the data.

Comment: Hi I have posted another answer please check if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Mike I have created a Dataset and see how the pivot can be generated with **reshape** package. This can be downloaded as excel/csv. Hope this helps you

`ID<-c(2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018,2019,2020,2021,2022,2023)`

`type<-c('Spices','Spices','Fruit','Fruit','Fruit','Spices','Spices','Spices','Spices','Spices','Fruit','Fruit','Spices','Fruit','Fruit','Fruit','Fruit','Spices','Fruit','Fruit')`

`state<-c('New Jersey','New Jersey','New Jersey','New Jersey','New Jersey','New Jersey','Florida','Michigan','Michigan','New Jersey','New Jersey','New Jersey','New Jersey','New Jersey','New Jersey','Florida','Michigan',
        'Michigan','Florida','Florida')`

```
price<-c (1442,639,71,22,1185,508,434,24,528,8,41,82,2994,385,545,1850,2966,31,536,42)

data=data.frame(ID,type,state,price)

library(reshape)

data.m=melt(data, id=c(1:4), measure=c(4))

df1 <-cast(data.m, ID~type+value, sum)
```

`#for adding grand total`

```
df2<- cast(data.m, ID~type+value, sum, margins=c("grand_row"))

#for adding filter

df3 <- cast(data.m, ID~type+value, sum, margins=c("grand_row"),subset=state=="Florida")
```

df1, df2 and df3 are the pivots.

Comment: Does this actually create an *Excel pivot table* that can be used with an *Excel slicer*, though? Or is it just pre-transformed data dumped into Excel? I need the built-in Pivot Table and Slicer functionality from Excel.

Comment: Yes you need to do that.